# Alexa Skill Kit : how does Alexa Echo App display the content instead of just speech

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I many to receive response from Alexa Voice Service but the response looks like it only send me back audio data not the text data which I have defined in the schema e.g. stuff in the card tag.

In Alexa App, after requesting what is the weather today, the app will display the result not only speech.

Does anyone know how to receive that data. I want receive some data and trigger some action on a device e.g. open an application

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can check the cards of your request in this Alexa Amazon official ANDROID app, login with the User account and check all your requests there.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.dee.app

If the Alexa App is not available in your region then use the APK from below.
http://www.apkmonk.com/app/com.amazon.dee.app/

Let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found out : The Alexa Voice can only response audio to the user.